# Apache rewrite rule for whole directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to put a rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule /test /my/long/path/index.html
```

but my index.html fetch other files, by ajax, so it's not working simple like this. I need a rule for all subfiles of the directory
I tried:

```
RewriteRule /test /my/long/path/
RewriteRule /test/* /my/long/path/*
```

but I end up with a funny redirect  http://my.domain.co/test/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/

Sorry for my ignorance in Apache, and thx

Comment: I think you would require to have a `/` after /test. Otherwise with references like `<img src="plaatje.jpg" />` the browser would look for plaatje.jpg in the root (/), and not in the /test folder.

Comment: RewriteRule /test/ /my/long/path/index.html, does the same, the page cannot load completely because /my/long/path/index.html fetch some files like /my/long/path/file.json, and they are not found at /test/file.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RewriteRule is not valid. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^test(/.*)?$ my/long/path$1
```

Comment: I tried but browser says http://my.domain.co/test/index.html or http://my.domain.co/test is not found

Comment: Did you set `RewriteEngine On` and put the .htaccess into the root directory?

Comment: yes for RewriteEngine On, and didn't put .htaccess, is it needed for url rewriting?

Comment: Where did you store your RewriteRule?

Comment: in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default (ubuntu) <VirtualHost *:80>

 RewriteEngine   On
 RewriteRule ...

Comment: Not working yet "Not Found" error, I have put a .htaccess with RewriteEngine   On
RewriteRule ^test(/.*)$ very/long/path$1, at the root of the server, the folder /test in not existing, but I would like to be redirected from my.domain.co/test to the existing resource folder at my.domain.co/very/long/path

Comment: the .htaccess file just need those 2 lines? and where it should be placed on server root? or on serverroot/test/ ?

Comment: Yes, only those 2 lines. You have to place the .htaccess in your domain's root directory. Note: I made a small edit at the RewriteRule above.

Comment: tx, but I put it, in the apache2 conf file, like this RewriteRule ^/test(/.*) /my/long/path$1, trailing slashes, it seems working, so not in htaccess but I will try when possible