# convert nginx redirect to .htaccess apache (drupal 7)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, nginx, drupal-7

I have to redirect url in .htaccess:

original: `/mobile/blog/`
redirect : `/blog/`
I tried:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile/blog/`
 `RewriteRule ^mobile/blog/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L]`

Without success.
I aslo have these nginx redirect that need to be in .htaccess.

`rewrite ^/items/(.+)/(.*) /search/$2 permanent;`
`rewrite ^/items/(.*) /search/$1 permanent;`
`rewrite ^/topic/onlyon $scheme://$host/tags/onlyon permanent;`

Any help and documentation is appreciated.

Comment: why would you switch from nginx to apache?

Comment: That is above my pay grade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Drupal sometimes updates the .htaccess file and Drupal often maintains a set of redirect internally it often makes sense to handle redirects using the [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).

That said, if you need or want to do redirects in the .htaccess you can do that just fine.  The first redirect you can do without rewrite, you can use [Apache's redirect directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect permanent /oldlocation /newlocation
```

To move everything in a directory using rewrite you can use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^items(/.*)?$ /search/$1
```

See also: [Apache rewrite rule for whole directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659594/apache-rewrite-rule-for-whole-directory)

Comment: Thanks. The apache redirect works. But what i don't understand is that the rewrite rule does not work. Is it because Drupal does not really has folders but nodes? (I am new to Drupal might be a newbe reasoning)

Comment: .htaccess directives happen before Drupal is running, so how Drupal is structured only matters if you need to check to see if a file/node exists (and then you have to make sure there is a file or do your redirect in the redirect module or similar). Reason #1 that rewrites fail: mod_rewrite isn't running on the server.  Reason #2 the rewrite matching pattern is wrong.