# htaccess redirect with variable path match

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from example.com to example2.com where the first path segment is a variable:

I.e. to redirect from:

- example.com/**aariz**/name/meaning/english
- example.com/**arif**/name/meaning/english
- example.com/**adil**/name/meaning/english
- example.com/**ayat**/name/meaning/english

To:

- example2.com/aariz/name/meaning/english
- example2.com/arif/name/meaning/english
- example2.com/adil/name/meaning/english
- example2.com/ayat/name/meaning/english

This is the code I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)/name/           [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) https://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But in all cases it's redirecting to `example2/name/meaning/English` - the first path segment is missing.

How can I redirect maintaining the whole path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache rewrite rule for whole directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659594/apache-rewrite-rule-for-whole-directory)

Comment: @AD7six No. It doesn't works for me

Comment: `RewriteRule /` <- the error is this forward slash - just delete it. There may be a better duplicate, but it's a common question. See [the examples in the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) if unclear :).